# Is it possible to customize hub site programatically?

Tags: spfx, hub-site

Is it possible to customize hub site programmatically using SPFx solution? My intention to ask this question was, i want to completely customize the menu with some images for every sublink. This is not possible with OOB capabilities even with megamenu too

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot customize the out-of-the-box menu (not in any supported way) but you can use a SPFx Application Customizer Extension to build a completely custom menu. The screen capture below shows an example that the company I work for built for a client.

For more details on how to implement something like this please see [React Menu Footer Classic Modern](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-menu-footer-classic-modern).

[image: Custom menu]